# gdb seems to affect function return value that's stored in $eax?

Tags: linux, gcc, gdb, return, printf

"printf" returns the number of characters really printed, so I had:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  printf("1");
  printf("55555");
  printf("10________");
  printf("13___________");
  printf("18________________");
  printf("28__________________________");
}
```

This program will output

```
15555510________13___________18________________28__________________________
```

Then I tried to debug it in gdb and check the return value of gdb:

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x804844c: file testp.c, line 4.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/a/cpp/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main () at testp.c:4
4     printf("1");
(gdb) n               # will return "1" to $eax
5     printf("55555");
(gdb) p $eax          # I expect it will print "1" here, wrong!
$1 = 49
(gdb) n
6     printf("10________");
(gdb) p $eax          # I expect it will print "5" here, right!
$2 = 5
(gdb) n
7     printf("13____________");
(gdb) p $eax          # I expect it will print "10" here, right!
$3 = 10
```

As you could see, when the first printf is run, the $eax value is not as my expectation. Later values are seems correct.
Why is this? Why first printf doesn't return a "1" to $eax? I suppose c style ABI stores return value in $eax, right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gcc can replace calls to `printf` with more efficient code, such as calls to `puts` or `putchar`, in certain cases where the optimization won't change the documented behavior of the functions (for example, when the output doesn't require any formatting to be done and you don't use the return value). That's what's happening here. You're seeing 49 in %eax because `putchar` returns either the character that was output, or `EOF`.

```
(gdb) disass /m main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
3   {
   0x000000000040057d <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x000000000040057e <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp

4     printf("1");
   0x0000000000400581 <+4>: mov    $0x31,%edi
   0x0000000000400586 <+9>: callq  0x400450 <putchar@plt>

5     printf("55555");
   0x000000000040058b <+14>:    mov    $0x400664,%edi
   0x0000000000400590 <+19>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000400595 <+24>:    callq  0x400460 <printf@plt>
```

To get gcc to generate calls to `printf` all the time, you can use the `-fno-builtin-printf` option.

Comment: Thanks, -fno-builtin-printf works for me. I was just confused, I didn't use "-O" option or do any optimization, why gcc still does some optimization? How to manually disable it completely?

Comment: Even with `-O0`, gcc will still substitute equivalent, more efficient code for standard functions like `printf` and `strcpy`, unless you give it the `-fno-builtin` or `no-builtin-nameoffunc` option.